# Synonym for "academic year" when talking about primary/secondary schools not universities

Tags: synonyms, word-choice

Academic years in my culture are specified using two-year format e.g. academic year 2014-2015 (which starts in September 2014 and ends in June 2015). The term "academic" bears, in my opinion, much of an academic context. Are there any alternative options to be used when referring to such a year in a primary or secondary education context?

Comment: "School year" is also OK.

Comment: I don't think I understand your complaint about using *academic year* in primary or secondary education.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I am not comfortable with it because it contains academy not school. This is most probably because am an ESL guy.

Comment: Jason: Relatively speaking, *academic* is a "50 cent word", which why many people would go for @GEdgar's "5 cent" alternative in a  primary/secondary school context ('cos they haven't even *learned* the more "erudite" term yet! :)

Comment: In present-day US English "academic" is used of anything having to do with studies as opposed to the social, artistic, recreational and athletic activities carried on in schools. It has no necessary relationship to "academy" in any sense of that term.

Comment: GEdgar: Your comment is an answer, why not write it up and get credit?

Comment: @StoneyB Ditto in the UK, but 'academic' also carries the broader sense 'relating to educational issues / institutions' as I'm sure it does in the US. Just to confuse the issue, we now have schools known as 'academies' (to supposedly boost their image).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We have some prestigious old schools with 'academy' in their 19th-century names, and some newer schools that put 'academy' in their names to appear prestigious. I think the only place where 'academy' doesn't come off as pretentious is in arts training: music, dance, theatre, graphic arts.

Comment: John Lawler's version being pseudo-pretentious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"School year" is also OK.

But "academic year" is fine, even for elementary schools.

Maybe "school year" can be used so that there is no objection even from those who think school has mainly some purpose other than academics.

By the way, I don't think "academic" will suggest "academy" to most people.

Comment: Probably that misconception more typically occurs for ESL people like me.